# Run command flutter in Android Studio terminal problem

Tags: flutter, android-studio, terminal, command

In Android Studio Flutter project, whenever I run anything on terminal for example `flutter pub add device_preview` it will pop up `How do you want to open this file?` Is this normal? How do I actually run this command?

[image: pop up message]

I run command help 'help' seems it give a response, so could it be something to do with my Flutter? If I run `flutter doctor` on CMD it's all fine all tick. My flutter PATH environment is fine. I can produce bundle, app, run preview on other project, but I want to get deep down to this issue to run flutter command manually in the terminal.

[image: help response]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I answer my own question, but the way I resolve this issue by delete an empty 1 kilobyte file name 'flutter' in my Document, which flutter try to refer to despite my PATH environment variable already indicate correctly flutter\bin folder is on C drive, then I restart PC. Guess what flutter create another empty flutter file this time on system32 so delete and restart again then it work. Initially my flutter\bin file was with other tool folder too so I just separate it make flutter standalone folder C:\flutter instead of C:\ssc\flutter what not.